# Cannot read property 'on' of undefined at new JsonFormatter

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

I am trying to generate a html report using **cucumber-html-reporter**

getting error:

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
at new JsonFormatter (C:\path-to-project\node_modules\cucumber\src\formatter\json_formatter.js:21:5)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\path-to-project\test\reporting\CucumberReportExtension.ts:43:27)
```

Checked [release notes](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)  for undefined parameters. I am not sure whether this issue belong to that!
If so, can anyone please drive me to fix this issue.

Also please let me know in case you have better solution to generate reports with cucumber-protractor using typescript. (Please consider the below versions too)

Protractor version: **5.1.2**

Cucumber version: **3.0.0**

***ScenarioHook.ts***

```
import {defineSupportCode} from "cucumber";
import {CucumberReportExtension} from 
"../reporting/CucumberReportExtension";

defineSupportCode(({AfterAll}) => {

  AfterAll(async () => {
     new CucumberReportExtension().myJsonFormatter;
  });
});
```

***CucumberReportExtension.ts***

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { mkdirp } from 'mkdirp';
import * as report from 'cucumber-html-reporter';
let Cucumber = require('cucumber');

export class CucumberReportExtension {

 private jsonDir = process.cwd() + "/reports/json";
 private htmlDir = process.cwd() + "/reports/html";
 private jsonFile = this.jsonDir + "/cucumber_report.json";

 private cucumberReporterOptions = {
    theme: "bootstrap",
    jsonFile: this.jsonFile,
    output: this.htmlDir + "/cucumber_reporter.html",
    reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,
    metadata: {
        "App Version":"0.0.1",
        "Test Environment": "TestingMicroSheet",
        "Browser": "Chrome  59.0.945",
        "Platform": "Windows 10",
        "Parallel": "Scenarios",
        "Executed": "Local"
    }
 };

 private CreateReportFile(dirName, fileName, fileContent) {
    //Check if the directory exist
    if (!fs.existsSync(dirName))
        mkdirp.sync(dirName);
    try {
        fs.writeFileSync(fileName, fileContent);
    }
    catch (message) {
        console.log("Failed to create File/Directory :" + message);
    }
 }

 private GenerateCucumberReport(cucumberReportOption){
    report.generate(cucumberReportOption);
 }

 myJsonFormatter = new Cucumber.JsonFormatter({
    log: jLog => {
        this.CreateReportFile(this.jsonDir, this.jsonFile, jLog);
        this.GenerateCucumberReport(this.cucumberReporterOptions);
    }
 });
}
export let JsonFormatter = new CucumberReportExtension().myJsonFormatter;
```

***config.ts***

```
import { Config } from 'protractor';

export let config: Config = {

 seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

 framework: 'custom',
 frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
 specs: ["../features/*.feature"],

 baseUrl: "http://localhost:4200/",

 cucumberOpts: {
    compiler: "ts:ts-node/register",
    strict: true,
    format: ['json:../reporting/results.json'],
    require: ['../steps/*.js', '../hooks/*.js'],
    tags: '@smoke'
 }
}
```

***package.json***

```
{
  "name": "protractor-cucumber-sample",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
  "start": "node ./bin/www"
   },
  "dependencies": {
  "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.53",
  "body-parser": "~1.17.1",
  "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
  "debug": "~2.6.3",
  "express": "~4.15.2",
  "jade": "~1.11.0",
  "morgan": "~1.8.1",
  "serve-favicon": "~2.4.2"
   },
 "devDependencies": {
 "@types/chai": "^4.0.3",
 "@types/cucumber": "^2.0.3",
 "@types/mkdirp": "^0.5.0",
 "chai": "^4.1.1",
 "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
 "cucumber": "^3.0.0",
 "cucumber-html-reporter": "^2.0.3",
 "jasmine": "^2.7.0",
 "jasminewd2": "^2.1.0",
 "protractor-cucumber-framework": "^4.0.2",
 "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
 "typescript": "^2.4.2"
  }
 }
```

Please let me know if additional information required which helps you to address this issue.

If this is not the right forum, could you please reply me with the right forum details to post this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a typescript error, i think you don't have node types installed in your project! Also which version of node are you using?

Comment: I am using Node version **v6.11.2**. In the above error message `\node_modules\cucumber\src\formatter\json_formatter.js:21:5` it is referring to `cucumber\src\` folder. I have installed cucumber both locally and globally. I couldn't find `src` folder.

Comment: Instead I found `options.eventBroadcaster.on('test-run-finished', _this.onTestRunFinished.bind(_this));` in `cucumber\lib\formatter\json_formatter.json`. Tried to pass [test-step-finished](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/pull/172) for **eventBroadcaster** in **CucumberReportExtension.ts**. No luck. Getting the same error

Comment: it has nothing to do with src folder, you wouldn't find it as it compiles . Try installing node types and check if the error goes- `npm i -D @types/node`

Comment: Also you have to point your `@types` in `tsconfig.json`. Please check my repo example [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/igniteram/protractor-cucumber-typescript/blob/master/tsconfig.json#L12)

Comment: Still facing the same issue. I installed node `npm i -D @types/node`. And my tsconfig.json as
`{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "typeRoots": [ "./node_modules/@types" ],
    "types": ["node","cucumber"],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
 "strict": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2015"
     ]
  }
}`

Comment: your target should be es6, that is the issue. cucumber and protractor latest use es6 features

Comment: Any specification for `lib`? I changed `target` to `es6`. And tested it with both `2015` and `2016`. Still facing the same error

Answer (score 1):

With latest cucumber 3.0, you have to pass node `event emitter` to your custom formatters. For details on how node events work please go through this link - https://nodejs.org/api/events.html

Now to use this in your `CucumberReportExtension.ts`

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { mkdirp } from 'mkdirp';
import * as report from 'cucumber-html-reporter';
let Cucumber = require('cucumber');
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';
const eventBroadcaster = new EventEmitter();

export class CucumberReportExtension {

private jsonDir = process.cwd() + "/reports/json";
private htmlDir = process.cwd() + "/reports/html";
private jsonFile = this.jsonDir + "/cucumber_report.json";

private cucumberReporterOptions = {
theme: "bootstrap",
jsonFile: this.jsonFile,
output: this.htmlDir + "/cucumber_reporter.html",
reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,
metadata: {
    "App Version":"0.0.1",
    "Test Environment": "TestingMicroSheet",
    "Browser": "Chrome  59.0.945",
    "Platform": "Windows 10",
    "Parallel": "Scenarios",
    "Executed": "Local"
  }
};

private CreateReportFile(dirName, fileName, fileContent) {
//Check if the directory exist
if (!fs.existsSync(dirName))
    mkdirp.sync(dirName);
try {
    fs.writeFileSync(fileName, fileContent);
}
catch (message) {
    console.log("Failed to create File/Directory :" + message);
 }
}

private GenerateCucumberReport(cucumberReportOption){
report.generate(cucumberReportOption);
 }

 myJsonFormatter = new Cucumber.JsonFormatter({
       eventBroadcaster: eventBroadcaster,
       log: jLog => {
           this.CreateReportFile(this.jsonDir, this.jsonFile, jLog);
           this.GenerateCucumberReport(this.cucumberReporterOptions);
        }
 });
}
export let JsonFormatter = new CucumberReportExtension().myJsonFormatter;
```

**Note:** I haven't tested it yet, But it should work!, I will update the answer once I am finished experimenting with new cucumber 3.0 features!